# Testion controler method in symfony (phpUnit)

Tags: symfony, phpunit

i need some help i want to write a unit test about a controler method , i have searched for examples and tested a lot of method's but none of them has worked:

Here is my controller:

```
class ComputerController extends Controller
{
/**
     * @Route("/list-computers.html", name="back_computer_list")
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    function listComputerAction()
    {
        $ad = $this->get("ldap_service");
        $computers = $ad->getAllComputer();
        return $this->render('BackBundle:Computer:list.html.twig', array(
            "computers" => $computers,
        ));
    }
```

I have tried to test it with mock like this:

```
class ComputerController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var EngineInterface
     */
    private $templating;


    public function setTemplating($templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }
and i have created a test method:

class ComputerControllerTest extends  TestCase {

    public function testlistComputerAction(){
        $templating = $this->getMockBuilder('BackBundle\Controller\ComputerController')->getMock();
        $computers = [1,2];
        $templating->expects($this->once())
            ->method('render')
            ->with('BackBundle:Computer:list.html.twig', array(
                "computers" => $computers))
            ->will($this->returnValue( $computers));

        $controller = new ComputerController();
        $controller->setTemplating($templating);

        $this->assertEquals('success', $controller->listComputerAction());
    }
```

When i start executing phpunit , i have this warning"Trying to configure method "render" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static"

I would be thankful if someone has an idea about this

Comment: The reason you don't find much info about unit testing controller actions is that as a rule, there is no need to unit test controller actions.  Write a unit test for your ldap service.  If you really feel the urge to test your controller wiring then write a functional test per the documentation.

Comment: Thank's for your response, i thought that also at the begining because i didn't find much info about that, so know i will try to test ldapservice method's even if i don't think that there is much info about that either but i will try

Comment: Keep in mind that your ldap service probably uses some sort of ldap library and there is not no need to test the library.  You just want to test that your own ldap service code is calling the right stuff.

Comment: Jist another question please, what do you mean by ldap library that i caanot test for example i have method's for adding users editing delete also add users to group (modify,delete..) and thoses methods uses ldap functions so how can i test them?

Comment: @cerad, which methods are useful to be tested in a controler please, beacause i have (the following methods : addaction,edit,remove and i don't know if there is a utility to test them or how can i do that?)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to Test a method in ldapService : Here is the method's of the service that i want to test

```
/**
     * @return bool|resource
     */
    public function getLdapBind()
    {
        if (!$this->ldapBind) {

            if ($this->getLdapConnect()) {
                $this->ldapBind = @ldap_bind($this->ldapConnect, $this->ldapUser, $this->ldapPass);
            }
        }
        return $this->ldapBind;

    }


    /**
     * @param $ldapUser
     * @param $password
     * @return bool
     */
    function isAuthorized($ldapUser, $password)
    {
        $result = false;
        if ($this->ldapConnect) {
            $result = @ldap_bind($this->ldapConnect, $ldapUser, $password);
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Here is the test (using Mock):

```
<?php

namespace BackBundle\Tests\Service;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use BackBundle\Service\LdapService;
use PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_InvocationMocker;

class LdapServiceTest extends  TestCase {



  public function testgetLdapConnect()
    {
//        $LdapService = new LdapService();
        $ldapMock = $this->getMockBuilder( 'LdapService')->setMethods(['getLdapBind'])->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
        $ldapMock->expects($this->once())
//                ->method()
                ->with(array('ldap_bind', 'mike', 'password'))
            ->will($this->returnValue(true));

        $ldapMock->isAuthorized('mike', 'password');
    }
}
```

But i have a warning that i can't resolve : "Method name matcher is not defined, cannot define parameter matcher without one"

If someone , has an idea about that please

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, there is nothing useful to test in that three-line controller. #1 is the service container, and #3 is the Twig subsystem. Line #2 can be unit tested on it's own.

With more complex controllers, I have found that making them a service where all the dependencies are passed in, either by constructor, or into the action itself does make slightly more complex controllers quite easy, but very few need that anyway.